# angular 2 Is it possible to list that have inheritance item

Tags: inheritance, angular

I'm newbie with angular 2
I have a question but doesn't try it yet.
I want to create a List of Todo list
but item in this list have different Component & Class (but every Component inheritance from same Parent)

```
class Todo {}
class TodoPic extends Todo {}
class TodoVideo extends Todo {}

@Component({
    selector: 'todo',
    template: '...'
})
class AbstractTodoComponent {
    todo: Todo;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'todo-pic',
    template: '...'
})
class TodoPicComponent extends AbstractTodoComponent {}

@Component({
    selector: 'todo-video',
    template: '...'
})
class TodoVideoComponent extends AbstractTodoComponent {}
```

and use like this

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: '<todo *ngFor="let item in todoList"></todo>'
})
class AppComponent {
    todoList: Todo[]
    constructor() {
        todoList.push(new TodoPic())
        todoList.push(new TodoVideo())
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `AbstractTodoComponent` is a regular class, you do can inherit it as a regular class. About the conditional rendering (which seems what you are asking), it seems the better approach is to use `*ngIf` or `[ngSwitch]`.

Comment: Do you have any approach better than `*ngIf` or `ngSwitch`. I see Dynamic Content Loader but It's replace content not the component

Comment: Actually, you could use `DynamicComponentLoader` as alternative. I added an answer with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could leverage [`DynamicComponentLoader`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html) to create the components dynamically, according to the type of each `todo`.

Check a [**demo plunker here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/44MOkmCYu7DdBQzl748g?p=preview).

Important code:

```java
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: 'stuff before<hr><div #todoLocation></div><hr>stuff after'
})
class AppComponent {

  todoList: Todo[] = [new TodoPic(), new TodoVideo()];

  @ViewChild('todoLocation', {read: ViewContainerRef}) todoLocation:ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private dcl: DynamicComponentLoader) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.todoList.forEach(todo => this.loadComponentForTodo(todo));
  }

  loadComponentForTodo(todo: Todo) {
    let componentForType = this.inferComponentForType(todo);
    // this is where the component is created and loaded
    this.dcl.loadNextToLocation(componentForType, this.todoLocation)
    .then((c:ComponentRef) => {
              c.instance.todo = todo;
    });
  }

  inferComponentForType(todo: Todo) {
    let componentForType = AbstractTodoComponent;
    if (todo instanceof TodoPic) {
      return TodoPicComponent;
    } if (todo instanceof TodoVideo) {
      return TodoVideoComponent;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: but how can I filter todo item, if I have search box ?
because this technic doesn't use ngFor